# -encoding UTF-8 Java compile error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am getting an error when I try to run my Java program, I never came across this before and when I searched online I could not find anything of help.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-sun/bin/javac -encoding UTF-8  -classpath ':*:/usr/share/java/*' Solution.java 1> compile.err 2>&1
```

My Java project code:

```
public class Encircular {
    static String[] find(String[] commands) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        boolean goUp = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < commands.length(); i++) {
            switch (commands.charAt(i)) {
                case 'G' :
                    if (goUp) {
                        y++;
                    } else {
                        x++;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'L' :
                    goUp = true;
                    break;
                case 'R' :
                    goUp = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
            return "YES";
        }
        return "NO";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(doesCircleExist("GLGLG"));
        System.out.println(doesCircleExist("GRGL"));
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it is displaying this on my console /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-sun/bin/javac -encoding UTF-8  -classpath ':*:/usr/share/java/*' Solution.java 1> compile.err 2>&1

Comment: This is a compile command for your java file. The output (and error) of the compile process is stored to the "compile.err" text file. How do you call your "program" (command line)? Seems to be some kind of wrapper script.

Comment: @Jackie Instead of posting as Comment, edit your Question to provide further details. Your readers should not have to plow through comments to understand your question.

Comment: That `/usr/lib/jvm`… text is not an error.  It’s the system showing you the full command that it’s executing.